# visual studio code not working c# cannot debug omnisharp problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, omnisharp

So im a bit pissed off as visual studio code is such a good program but this issue ive had is now over a year old. I recently came back to see if it was fixed but it was not so im asking for help this time.
So the error message i get when pressing F5 in order to debug my code is:

> Cannot create .NET debug configurations. The OmniSharp server is still initializing or has exited unexpectedly.

when i try to press view > command palette > Generate assets... i get this message:

> Unable to generate assets to build and debug. OmniSharp server is not running.

So im pretty much unable to code in vscode and ive not found any fixes such as uninstalling, installing mono
Here is my dotnet info

```
 PS C:\Users\giggi\Desktop\program\vscode\notworking> dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.401
 Commit:    39d17847db

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19041
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.401\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.7
  Commit:  fcfdef8d6b

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Comment: When you uninstalled, did you delete all files that VS Code leaves everywhere in your `C:\Users\{user}` folder? Also, given that you're on Windows, you'll have a much better time off using VS Community

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes i have deleted all there and in the other places like appdata. I have vs but i like the speed of vs code and i also do python and web so i would prefer to do everything from vs code